# iOS UITextField- dismissing custom inputView

Tags: ios, uitextfield, inputview

I am using a custom inputView for some textfield, however when i call resignFirstResponder on the textfield, the custom input view does not dismiss...any suggestions?

```
UITextField *f=[[UITextfield alloc] init];
 UIView *view=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame..];
   [f setInputView:view]; //random example of how to set a textfields input view to a custom view
```

After some research, this issue only occurs when working with a viewController thats presented in a modal view...it works ok otherwise...

Thanks

-Daniel

Comment: by custom text field, you mean you have an object of `UITextField`? Can you post some code?

Comment: i mean the inputView property of a UITextfield, check out the snippet of code

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?  Do you have code of where you are calling resignFirstResponder?  Because that should be working

Answer (score 7):

Instead of calling `resignFirstResponder`, you should call `endEditing:` on the view itself or any of its superviews. `endEditing:` will search all subviews for any view that has first responder status, and ask it to resign.

`endEditing:` takes a boolean flag as a parameter. If set, it will force the first responder to resign; otherwise, you can allow it to keep focus (if input is invalid, for example). For a UITextField, this is determined by the delegate's `shouldEndEditing:` method.

In general, a good pattern to use is:

```
- (void)saveAction:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.view endEditing:NO]) {
        NSString *text = self.textField.text;
        // save text, login, do whatever
    } else {
        // show an alert (or rely on whatever refused to resign to inform the user why)
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. It seems to work correctly if the view is just part of the normal window, but if it's in a modal window, the keyboard doesn't go away.. Any ideas?

Comment: You must call `endEditing:` on a view that is the parent of the first responder view. It's hard to say exactly what will work without knowing your view hierarchy, but you can try `self.view.window` or `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`.

Comment: cool, I'll try the window one. I'm calling it on a parent for sure, but it doesn't seem to work, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you use a modal view, make make sure to enable automatic keyboard dismissal. Add this code to your view controller:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: For anyone who chances on to this question: This answer is the correct solution and not the one about calling endEditing. See similar Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui