# keyboard - uinavigationcontroller - issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a view controller with a keyboard. When I push a new view controller onto the navigation stack the view controller slides out, then the keyboard slides out, then the new viewcontroller slides in....

How can I get it so the old viewcontroller and the keyboard slide out together....It is as if the keyboard is in a separate view to the view controller that uses it...

Answer (score 0):

You should hide the keyboard before pushing the new view. You can try this by calling this line of code before you push

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: hi I tried it but it doesn't work. The view currently on the stack is called lvc....I tried [lvc.view endEditing:YES]

Comment: How do you push your new view on the stack?

Comment: i have a uinavigationcontroller set up in my app delegate. i call [self.navigationController pushViewController: Animated]

Comment: Well yes. That's right. Than the code that I gave you should really do it. Just use the exact thing that I gave you.

Comment: Hmm, facebook doesn;t do this, they make the keyboard disappear as if it is in the same view

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I've used the solution proposed by Mihai in other scenarios. However, in this particular scenario (using a navigation controller) it has no effect. I found the solution in this SO question: [iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal ViewController presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui)