# iOS iPad app not hiding keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, uitextfield, uipopovercontroller

In my app I have a view that is a form that has quite a few inputs.
When the UITextField calls `textFieldDidBeginEditing`, it checks the tag and will bring up a UIPopoverController or the keyboard depending on the what the input is meant to be.

If the keyboard is up, I need it disappear when the user presses a textfield that brings up the popover. However I cannot make it disappear, I have tried every way to get rid of the keyboard but it just stays there. I have tried:

- calling `resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`
- calling `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in `textFieldDidEndEditing`
- calling `resignFirstResponder` AND `[self.view endEditing:YES]` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` checking for the previous tag is equal to a keyboard input text field.

Any ideas would be great.

I have ripped it out and and put it in a example project if anyone wants to see the exact behaviour.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/61692457/KB_Test.zip

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal view controller presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a Global UITextField in .h file

UITextField *txtfld;

Replace Your method textFieldDidBeginEditing with textFieldShouldBeginEditing and now write this code

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{

if (textField.tag == 1 || textField.tag==3)
{

    if(numPickerPopover == nil)
    {   

        numPicker = [[[NumPicker alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];

        numPicker.delegate = self;

        numPickerPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:numPicker];
        [numPickerPopover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(60.0, 260.0f)];
    }

    [numPickerPopover presentPopoverFromRect:textField.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    [txtfld resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}


if (textField.tag == 2)

{

    txtfld = textField;

    return YES;
}

return YES;    

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I took the idea and simplified it and it works a treat. Not sure why my way didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

To dismiss the keyboard when the user touches the textField that brought it up, add this method:

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

In Interface Builder, connect this method to the textField event you want, like touch up inside (or whatever is more appropriate).

Comment: I want the keyboard to disappear when the user touches another UITextField (not the same Text Field). I gave it a shot anyway but I am not using the Interface Builder, I added: `[tf3 addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];)` but that did not fire the event.

Comment: It should be easier if you want it dismissed when another TextField is touched as you can just link that textfield to the method that dismisses the keyboard in the IB. I am not sure of the non-IB way to link the 'Touch Up Inside' Event to the method.
Try NSLog to make sure event is fired, maybe it is but the keyboard isn't dismissed.

Comment: Thats what I have done using UITextFieldDelegate with textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing. But it didn't work.......