# Hide keyboard in ModalView (FormSheet) on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, keyboard

I'm trying to hide the iPad keyboard on a modal view, which has the FormSheet style. I tried to resignFirstResponder, but nothing happens. Is this a bug or doesn't this work at all?

best regards

EDIT

```
-(void)hideKeyboards 
{
 [emailField resignFirstResponder];
 [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
 [confirmPasswordField resignFirstResponder];
} 

-(IBAction)emailFieldDone:(id)sender
{
 [self hideKeyboards];
} 

-(IBAction)passwordFieldDone:(id)sender
{
 [self hideKeyboards];
} 

-(IBAction)confirmPasswordFieldDone:(id)sender
{ 
 [self hideKeyboards];
}
```

Comment: have you set delegate in .h file?

Comment: That's what i tried:
-(void)hideKeyboards {
    [emailField resignFirstResponder];
    [passwordField resignFirstResponder];
    [confirmPasswordField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(IBAction)emailFieldDone:(id)sender { [self hideKeyboards]; }
-(IBAction)passwordFieldDone:(id)sender { [self hideKeyboards]; }
-(IBAction)confirmPasswordFieldDone:(id)sender { [self hideKeyboards]; }

Comment: check have you set delegate to text fields in your xib or set textfield.delegate = self;

Comment: Yes, the delegates are set correctly. It works on iPhone, but not on iPad .. am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` to return NO as below fixed the same problem of mine. You need to override `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` of `UINavigationController`, not the own view controller, to fix this issue. Maybe use a category is a good idea:

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal {
    return NO;
}
```

Also, check this [iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal view controller presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui) question if you want to get a detailed explanation.

Comment: You need to override disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal of UINavigationController, not the own view controller.

Comment: Hello, i subclassed the navigationcontroller and override the disablesAut. method, but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can you paste out your code? This should work. So many people have used this to solve their problem. Check the link there are other ways to solve this problem. Try them.

Comment: I created a class called customNavigationController and pasted your code in it. I applied this custom class to my navigationcontroller. Then i tired the resignFirstResponder thing again, but that didn't work. The keyboard won't hide. :(

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH! I hate myself... Your solution works perfectly!! The problem was that i am pushing to a view, which has a becomeFirstResponder to a textfield inside of it :) So it disapears and appears right after it dissapeared... :) THANK's!

Answer (score 2):

try this if you are using textview

```
 Textviewobjectname.editable = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set delegates to all text field

```
  textField.delegate=self;
```