# ios textFieldDidEndEditing fires, but textFieldShouldReturn doesn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my app i'm using a `UITextField` collect a string value. Whenever i finish editing the field, `textFieldDidEndEditing` gets fired, but later `textFieldShouldReturn` never. What can be it's reason?

I provide some code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if(textField == self.urlPatternTextField) {

      /*do some stuff*/
    }
}

- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(id)sender {

    NSMutableArray* possibleReponders = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                                         self.urlPatternTextField, nil];

    for (UITextView* tv in possibleReponders) {
        if([tv isFirstResponder]) {

            [tv resignFirstResponder];
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

In textFieldDidEndEditing the if condition is true.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Sincerely,

Zoli

Comment: did you connect the delegate to files owner in IB?

Comment: Delegate is only reason for it..may be

Comment: of course. otherwise textFieldDidEndEditing wouldn't work either

Comment: yourTextField.delegate = self;

Comment: "Whenever i finish editing the field, textFieldDidEndEditing gets fired", --how your able to call this delegate method i.e., by clicking on any other text field or some thing else?

Comment: yes. or on the return key.

Comment: The answer lies within this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui

Answer (score 1):

> **textFieldShouldReturn:**
>
> Asks the delegate if the text field should
> process the pressing of the return button.
>
> ```
> - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> textField The text field whose return button was pressed.
>
> Return Value
> YES if the text field should implement its default behavior for the
> return button; otherwise, NO.
>
> Discussion **The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the
> return button. You can use this method to implement any custom
> behavior when the button is tapped.**

The method invokes **when return button is pressed**.Try it so

Comment: i changed the return value to NO, now when i press the return button textFieldShouldReturn fires, but it still doesn't dismiss the keyboard

Comment: Return Value YES if the text field should implement its default behavior for the return button;

Comment: call `[textField resignFirstResponder];` on both the methods `textFieldDidEndEditing` and `textFieldShouldReturn`

Comment: still nothing. Strange. I have implemented this like a 100 times before. However in this case the UIViewController is presented modally on the top of an other UIViewController. Could this mess things up?

Comment: @ZoltanVaradi- Strangly it happened with me. today i added manually delegate..have u done that

Comment: Turns out modal views do mess up the keyboard handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui