# How do I resign a first responder in a modal view with a Navigation Controller?

Tags: ios, keyboard, hide, searchbar

I am finding it quite impossible to resign the first responder in my Modal View that is a Navigation Controller.

I have a search bar that I use to search through a tableview.  I need to have it so that when I click on a cell, or navigate from the pushed view the keyboard disappears. I have tried calling

```
[_searchbar resignFirstResponder];
```

and doing a similar call for every view and subview in the modal view. Nothing causes the keyboard to hide.

Any ideas?

I've also tried using delegate methods, such as searchBarShouldEndEditing and also, calling the method on NavigationItemShouldPop.

I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Have you tried `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: I just gave it a try. I am not sure that I am doing it properly though.  Do I just use the above code and it should hide the keyboard, or do I need so have a method called that then resigns the repsonder?

Comment: Call it from the view controller and it should force all subviews to resign.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have it inside -(bool)searchBarShouldEndEditing and I call [_searchbar endEditing:YES]; within 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you have solved this already but this thread holds the key:

[iPad keyboard will not dismiss if modal ViewController presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-view-controller-presentation-style-is-ui)

For your particular case (same as mine) with the navigation controller within the modal form sheet look at the third answer.