# presenting a modal view controller while the keyboard is active

Tags: ios, uitextfield, first-responder, presentviewcontroller

So I basically have a form, consisting of several text fields. The user types into the fields as usual.  But the user also has the option of double-tapping a text field, which presents a modal view controller, allowing the user to choose from a number of options relating to that field.

Can I somehow present the modal "over" the keyboard, such that when it is dismissed, the keyboard is still active for the field that had been first responder before I presented the modal?

Right now, the keyboard dismisses while the modal appears, and reappears as the modal is dismissed.  It looks clunky to me, and distracting.  Would love to streamline it, and reduce the amount of animation onscreen.

Comment: `It looks clunky to me, and distracting.` Well that's how iOS handles modals.

Comment: please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3372333/ipad-keyboard-will-not-dismiss-if-modal-viewcontroller-presentation-style-is-uim

Comment: Sounding like there really is no way to do this.

Comment: Why didn't you select the answer by Rob B? Its excellent and he went to a lot of trouble to respond to you... You could do it now!

Comment: another working example working with a uiwindow is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32647890/show-uialertcontroller-over-keyboard

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Edit: I've updated this answer for iOS 12 and Swift. The revised example project (containing new Swift and updated Objective-C implementations) is [here](https://github.com/robbajorek/ModalOverlayIOS).

---

You can create a new `UIWindow` and place that over the default window while hiding the keyboard's window.

---

[image: Animated example of overlaying a new UIWindow over the existing one]

---

I have an example project on Github [here](https://github.com/robbajorek/ModalOverlayIOS), but the basic process is below.

- Create a new `UIViewController` class for your modal view. I called mine `OverlayViewController`. Set up the corresponding view as you wish. Per your question you need to pass back some options, so I made a delegate protocol `OverlayViewController` and will make the primary window's root view controller (class `ViewController`) our delegate.

```
protocol OverlayViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func optionChosen(option: YourOptionsEnum)
}
```

- Add some supporting properties to our original view controller.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  /// The text field that responds to a double-tap.
  @IBOutlet private weak var firstField: UITextField!
  /// A simple label that shows we received a message back from the overlay.
  @IBOutlet private weak var label: UILabel!
  /// The window that will appear over our existing one.
  private var overlayWindow: UIWindow?
```

- Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your `UITextField`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  // Set up gesture recognizer
  let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
  doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
  doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self

  firstField.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)

  firstField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

- `UITextField` has a built-in gesture recognizer, so we need to allow multiple `UIGestureRecognizer`s to operate simultaneously.

```
extension ViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  // Our gesture recognizer clashes with UITextField's.
  // Need to allow both to work simultaneously.
  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                         shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

- **This is the interesting part.** When the gesture recognizer is triggered, create the new `UIWindow`, assign your `OverlayViewController` as the root view controller, and show it. Note that we set the window level to `UIWindowLevelAlert` so it will appear in front. However, the keyboard will still be in front despite the alert window level, so we have to manually hide its window, too.

It is important to **not** set the new `UIWindow` as key or to change the first responder from the `UITextField` or the keyboard will be dismissed.

Previously (before iOS 10?) we could get away with `overlayWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()`, but now setting it as key will dismiss the keyboard. Also, the keyboard's window now has a non-standard `UIWindow.Level` value that is in front of every publicly defined value. I've worked around that by finding the keyboard's window in the hierarchy and hiding it instead.

```
@objc func handleDoubleTap() {
    // Prepare the overlay window
    guard let overlayFrame = view?.window?.frame else { return }
    overlayWindow = UIWindow(frame: overlayFrame)
    overlayWindow?.windowLevel = .alert
    let overlayVC = OverlayViewController.init(nibName: "OverlayViewController", bundle: nil)
    overlayWindow?.rootViewController = overlayVC
    overlayVC.delegate = self

    // The keyboard's window always appears to be the last in the hierarchy.
    let keyboardWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
    keyboardWindow?.isHidden = true
}
```

- The overlay window is now the original window. The user can now select whatever options you built into the overlay view. After your user selects an option, your delegate should take whatever action you intend and then dismiss the overlay window and show the keyboard again.

```
func optionChosen(option: YourOptionsEnum) {
  // Your code goes here. Take action based on the option chosen.
  // ...

  // Dismiss the overlay and show the keyboard
  overlayWindow = nil;
  UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.isHidden = false
}
```

- The overlay window should disappear, and your original window should appear with the keyboard in the same position as before.

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Does precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @DanM you thinks its an excellent answer (so do I) - so why not accept it as the correct answer? Is this my issue? I just don't see the checkmark?

Comment: Oops! I apparently somehow awarded the bounty without marking as correct... Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: does this work on iOS 11?  I'm seeing it as not working

Comment: I've updated the answer and example project. Let me know if you find any problems!

Comment: Awesome method Rob. Do you - or anyone else - know how to make this work when it's called from a modal? So basically my UITextField, whose keyboard I want to keep open, is itself already on a modal (modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen). I have tried all sorts of combinations but couldn't make it work. I can make the keyboardWindow disappear but the overlayWindow won't appear no matter what.

Answer (score 3):

I can't try this right now, but have implemented similar for other purposes. In the action for presenting the modal controller, I assume gesture recognizer or delegate method, first take a screenshot and place it in an `imageView` over the current subviews. Later when returning, simply remove the `imageView`.

Might sound crazy but I remember having done this for a transition where the keyboard moving during the transition caused similar clunky behavior. It was not difficult to implement at all.

If you have trouble trying it, perhaps someone will provide some code. I can reference my own work later and add an example, but not now.

Comment: I like this -- seems like a pretty easy way to get the effect I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

@Rob Bajorek's answer is excellent.
For iOS 9,10 there are small changes.  
 Instead of the code:

```
[self.overlayWindow setWindowLevel:UIWindowLevelAlert];
[self.overlayWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Put the following code:

```
NSArray *windows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];
UIWindow *lastWindow = (UIWindow *)[windows lastObject];
[self.overlayWindow setWindowLevel:lastWindow.windowLevel + 1];
[self.overlayWindow setHidden:NO];
```

Comment: you should use a comment for this type of suggestion.

Comment: When my reputation allows it, I will definitely use the comments. In any way, thank you Captain Hindsight.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keyboard to visible any of text accepting fields such `UITextField or UITextView or UISearchBar` should be the first responder and they should be visible in the view. Meaning responding view should be in the top level hierarchy in the window.

If you don't need this effect, Instead of presenting a `ViewController` you can add `ViewController.view` as a subview of your self.view with animation.

Comment: Would that not keep the keyboard on top of whatever view I was presenting?

Comment: Yes it will. Better you keep your view above the keyboard

Comment: Right -- so does not do what I was hoping to do.  I wonder if I added the view directly to the window, if that would work?

Answer (score 1):

You have access to the frame of the keyboard in iOS.

You need to implement code to listen to the keyboard notifications (like UIKeyboardWillShowNotification and UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification). The notification will send you informations about the frame of the keyboard.

Giva a look to the description of the "Keyboard Notification User Info Keys" in the [windows reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keyboard_Notification_User_Info_Keys).

You'll find useful for you purpose:

> **UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey** The key for an NSValue object containing a CGRect that identifies the bounds rectangle of the
>   keyboard in window coordinates. This value is sufficient for obtaining
>   the size of the keyboard. If you want to get the origin of the
>   keyboard on the screen (before or after animation) use the values
>   obtained from the user info dictionary through the
>   UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey or UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey
>   constants.

With the information of the keyboard frame you can show there you modal view.

Comment: Don't quite understand how that helps me cover the keyboard w/ the modal?

Comment: If you have the frame of the keyboard in the window coordinate you can place there the view you need to show as modal

Comment: Ah, so you're saying add the modal's view directly to the window?

Comment: If you need you can use the "convertRect:" methods of the UIView/UIWindow classes to translate the coordinate in the view/windows space of your preference

Comment: No, i'm saying that you have the frame in windows coordinate as i a wrote above you can translate it in what are the coordinate of the view of your choice

Comment: Oh... OK, I think I wasn't clear enough in my question. I want the modal to appear so it is *covering* the keyboard, I.e. The keyboard is not visible through the modal, but as the modal is dismissed it reveals the keyboard already in place.

Comment: If you want an advice on that, you can write a custom controller that is able to provide that type of modal view. IF you attach views to window you don't get the rotations for free.

Comment: You can still implement notifications to implement rotations in a view attached to the window, but it requires more work.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an tap gesture in your textfield and a UITextfield *flagTextfield;

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(DoubleTapMethod:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
[self.txtTest addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];


-(void)DoubleTapMethod:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{

     [flagTextfield resignFirstResponder];
     NSLog(@"DoubleTap detected");
     //Set your logic on double tap of Textfield...
     //presents a modal view controller
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

        flagTextfield = textfield;
}
```