# Cannot dismiss iPad native keyboard after disabling third party keyboards

Tags: ios

I am disabling third party keyboard in my app, by following the standard approach:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier
```

{

```
if (extensionPointIdentifier == UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier)
{
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

This method is called even if no third party keyboard is installed in the device, meaning it is called when I am using the standard built-in keyboard.

In may app, I have many UITextFields interacting with the native keyboard,but I am not able to dismiss that keyboard. A tap on the right-bottom button is offering the option to dock or to split(which normally should happen only on long press)

If I remove the code above, everything works fine.
I thought that maybe it's a system wide bug, but text fields work fine in other apps like Safari.

Please advise

Comment: are you implementing textfield/textview delegates for dismissing keyboard or not?

Comment: I am not implementing any delegate, just using default UITextField behavior. Note that even with delegate, - (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField is never called when tapping on the keyboard dismiss button. Note also that resignFirstResponder works as expected.

Comment: Use `yourTextField.resignFirstResponder` to hide native keyboard.

Comment: I've found a solution. Following http://stackoverflow.com/a/5503637/331370, just override in my view controllers the disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal to return NO and it works. What's still weird is that the view controller is not modal.

Comment: The solution works only on simulator (iOS 9.1) not on devices. So the question remains open. Thanks for any advise.

Comment: The issue is not related to what I thought but rather on apparently a swizzling of NSTimer in app that forces the callback of the dismiss button long press to be called immediately on tap.