# Removing a Keyboard after text is entered into a TextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have made a text view in interface builder and when i type in my details into the box, clicking done doesn't minimise the keyboard.

How is this done?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828826/iphone-keyboard-done-button-and-resignfirstresponder

Answer (score 2):

UITextView does not have any methods which will be called when the user hits the return key. If you want the user to be able to add only one line of text, use a UITextField. Hitting the return and hiding the keyboard for a UITextView does not follow the interface guidelines.

Even then if you want to do this, implement the textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: method of UITextViewDelegate and in that check if the replacement text is \n, hide the keyboard.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-using-a-uitextview.html

[How to dismiss keyboard for UITextView with return key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703754/how-to-dismiss-keyboard-for-uitextview-with-return-key)

Comment: Sorry didnt see your answer so posted mine. It was similar to yours so I deleted my answer in all fairness. :)

Comment: @PARTH: Its nothing compared to what you did. AS I said I owe you one.

Comment: He is asking for the **Done** button, not the return key, if I read that correctly. ;)